# Where does reSharper store Shared Solution Templates?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, resharper

My re-sharper Shared Solution Templates are not sharing correctly accross users. I suspect this is because I'm not committing them to version control. So, which file is it that I need to commit in order to ensure other users pick up the Shared Solution Templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found it, never mind. The file is called

> <SolutionName>.5.1.ReSharper